# Creating background/throttled thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to execute a long-running piece of code in a "background" thread and by "background" I mean low-priority thread not .NET background term. I created a thread, set its priority to Lowest and still 100% CPU is used if no other threads are running. The situation improves when I manually call Thread.Sleep(1) but I don't want to change my code and controlling CPU utilization via Thread.Sleep is highly unaccurate.

I want some way of executing a piece of code which will be throttled to ensure CPU usage at 5%-10%. Also I don't want to change the code too much (it is quite complex).

Is it possible?

Comment: If no other thread is using the CPU then why does it matter?

Comment: What does a CPU usage at 5% to 10% give you apart from a good feeling? A similar amount of cycles will be spent to complete the task, only stretched out over a longer time. Note also that a short amount of high load is (on modern CPUs) much better in terms of energy consumption, because the CPU can earlier enter states of lower power consumption - something that may be important on portable machines or in a server farm.

Comment: You are probably right about 5%-10% - it is probably my human nature. Like I said, I don't mind this background synchronisation task being stretched 10-20 times - this is not a requirement. But high availability and fast execution of other threads is. The code is running on servers, and I'm not really worrying about energy consumption as long as the code meets business requirements.

Comment: I wasn't precise - there is another thread which is patiently waiting for client requests, most of the time doing nothing. But when the request comes it has to be executed immediately and it is CPU intensive (spread across multiple threads) although relatively short (0.1 - 0.2 sec). I cannot afford to have another thread running at 100% CPU when the request comes and delay its execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds a bit like you need to solve the wrong issue - instead of trying to throttle the thread to a set CPU usage (which I'm not sure you can do), is there something wrong with what the thread is doing/how it's doing it? i.e. if it uses 100% CPU, is there nothing you could do to that logic to make it less CPU intensive in the first place?

You may find you can rework/optimise it to prevent it being this intensive in the first place, hence solving the problem at the root.

UPDATE: periodically read the external sources using a timer. A good reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx). You will solve the root cause of the high CPU usage by not continually checking those sources, but by doing it periodically (e.g. even if you do it every 15 seconds say, that will make a vast difference)

Comment: I can add some Thread.Sleep but this is kind of messy. The process itself reads data from external sources and repopulate memory cache. I do not know when the data has been changed until I read it, so the "background" process is constantly enumerating/reading all data sources and refreshed memory cache. 

Data does not have to be up-to-date (I mean a few minutes delay is acceptable) but it needs to be highly accessible (hence data are always served from the memory cache).

Comment: This is the real problem - the constant reading of the data sources. The best solution is to only do it periodically, you can use a timer to do this. I'll update my answer to include a reference.

Comment: Thank you AdaTheDev - I'll read the referenced article and try to chop the code into more manageable chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should have your "background" thread check a shared boolean that is set when the high-priority thread is working and wait until it's unset.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the thread priority is not an absolute thing. It's relative to other threads in the program.

Setting the thread priority to Normal will mean that it gets an equal "share" of the processor time (with other Normal threads).

Setting the priority to Low (or Lowest) will mean that it gets less of the processor time compared to Normal threads in the same program, and setting it to High (or Highest) will mean that it gets more.

If there is only one thread then it will get as much CPU as it needs regardless of the priority you set.

As AdaTheDev says, if it's using 100% CPU then the issue is with your algorithm not how Windows is allocating processor time to the thread.